# Sql intersection query using only joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

Class(cID: int, cname: varchar(30))
qualifiedTeacher(pID : int, cID : int)

I need to find all qualified teachers that have both classes cname = "Math" and cname = "English".

I can only use joins since sub selects are not allowed. Here is my attempt, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
select  c.pID as id from qualifiedTeacher as c
inner join class as t on c.cID = t.cID and t.cname = "Math"
inner join class as a on c.cID = a.cID and a.cname = "English";
```

from this query I'm not getting any results even when valid teachers exist

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried doing it like this?

```
SELECT c.pID, c.cID as id from qualifiedTeacher as c
inner join class as t on c.cID = t.cID
inner join class as a on c.cID = a.cID
where t.cname = 'Math' AND a.cname = 'English';
```

Comment: this one also is not producing any result back

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select q.pid from qualifiedteacher as q
Inner join
Class as c
On
Q.cid = c.cid
Where c.class = “math” and “English”
```

Comment: this is giving unknown column math error

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join twice with different `ON` conditions. Especially when you're doing `INNER JOIN`. You just `JOIN` once and add `WHERE t.cname IN ()` like this:

```
SELECT c.pID as id FROM qualifiedTeacher AS c
INNER JOIN  Class AS t ON c.cID = t.cID WHERE t.cname IN ( "Math","English");
```

Here's a fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71de58884786b1fca7128d983f553189

**Update:**

If you're looking to find a teacher who teaches both instead of either one, you can simply add `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` like this:

```
SELECT c.pID as id FROM qualifiedTeacher AS c
INNER JOIN Class AS t ON c.cID = t.cID WHERE t.cname IN ("Math","English")
GROUP BY c.pID 
HAVING COUNT(t.cname) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need an 'and' operation instead of 'or'. This one returns if they teach either of english or math.

Comment: So you mean that if the teacher have both `"Math"` and `"English` correct?

Comment: Yup thats right

Answer (score 0):

Because join will filter to to only items that match on both sides you can use two joins to get the correct results

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Teacher as T
JOIN qualifiedTeacher qt1 on T.pID = qt1.pID and qt1.cname = 'Math'
JOIN qualifiedTeacher qt2 on T.pID = qt2.pID and qt2.cname = 'English'
```